# How to deliver app with prefilled realm-database

Tags: realm

I would like to deliver my app with already prefilled data in my realm database. Do I have to simply copy it to the documents directory or is there some other things to do?

Comment: Android / iOS or both?

Comment: iOS - does it make a difference?

Comment: Yes. @jpsim points you to the documentation for iOS (Objective-C). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26240286/use-pre-populated-databases-with-realm points to a more cross-environment solution using Realm.getInstance() of a *.realm file.

Answer (score 32):

Realm's documentation has a section on ["Bundling a Realm with an App"](http://realm.io/docs/cocoa/#bundling-a-realm-with-an-app):

> It’s common to seed an app with initial data, making it available to your users immediately on first launch. Here’s how to do this:
>
> 1. First, populate the realm. You should use the same data model as your final, shipping app to create a realm and populate it with the data you wish to bundle with your app. Since realm files are cross-platform, you can use an OS X app (see our JSONImport example) or your iOS app running in the simulator.
> 2. In the code where you’re generating this realm file, you should finish by making a compacted copy of the file (see -[RLMRealm writeCopyToPath:error:]). This will reduce the Realm’s file size, making your final app lighter to download for your users.
> 3. Drag the new compacted copy of your realm file to your final app’s Xcode Project Navigator.
> 4. Go to your app target’s build phases tab in Xcode and add the realm file to the “Copy Bundle Resources” build phase.
> 5. At this point, your bundled realm file will be accessible to your app. You can find its path by using [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:ofType:].
> 6. You can either create a read-only realm by calling [RLMRealm realmWithPath:readOnly:error:]. Or, if you’d like to create a writable realm file based on this initial data, you can copy the bundled file to your application’s Documents directory using [[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:toPath:error:] and then construct your new realm by using [RLMRealm realmWithPath:].
>
> You can refer to our [migration sample app](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/tree/master/examples/ios/objc/Migration) for an example of how to use a bundled realm file.

Comment: What about the instructions for Android? The documentation for Java is missing a similiar section.

Comment: You can see an example of how to bundle a Realm file in the Java migration example here: https://github.com/realm/realm-java/blob/master/examples/migrationExample/src/main/java/io/realm/examples/realmmigrationexample/MigrationExampleActivity.java.

Comment: See my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36850732/262789) for the Realm Android supported way of adding initial data.

Comment: @jpsim Is there any simple example for this particular case in iOS? Because migration is another case, there should be a simple example of it.

Comment: Migrating bundled Realm files is a superset of just using it without migration. Just remove the migration-related code if you're not interested in that part of the example.

Comment: what's the relative size of a .realm file and .json. i already populate realm with a json directly so im trying to see if it's worth it to convert them to .realm files

Comment: If your JSON file is large, I all but guarantee you that converting it to a Realm (and compacting that Realm) will yield a significantly smaller file, and you'll avoid the performance cost of deserializing the JSON & writing to the database on app launch.

Comment: This answer is still working in 2022. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

**Pre filled Realm-database For Android**

Put your realm database in res/raw folder

and execute following code in activity:

// Copying realm database

```
copyBundledRealmFile(this.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.default0), "default0.realm");

RealmConfiguration config0 = new RealmConfiguration.Builder()
            .name("default0.realm")
            .build();

realm = Realm.getInstance(config0);

private String copyBundledRealmFile(InputStream inputStream, String outFileName) {
    try {
        File file = new File(this.getFilesDir(), outFileName);
        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
        int bytesRead;
        while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buf)) > 0) {
            outputStream.write(buf, 0, bytesRead);
        }
        outputStream.close();
        return file.getAbsolutePath();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A much easier way is just creating an ad-hoc function to be called just when there is no data on your realm model ("MyModel", in this example), at first app launch:

```
let realm = try! Realm()
lazy var data: Results<MyModel> = { self.realm.objects(MyModel.self) }()    

func populateDefaultData() {
    
    if yourdata.count == 0 {
        
        try! realm.write() {
            let defaultData = ["Data1", "Data2", "Data3"]
            for data in defaultData {
                let newData = MyModel()
                newData.data = data
                realm.add(newData)
            }
        }
        data = realm.objects(MyModel.self)
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    populateDefaultData()
}
```